Can't apply tailwind gradient color
I'm really stuck in that app. I cant able to apply tailwind gradient color into my project. Please help me.
Header.tsx
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { twMerge } from "tailwind-merge";
interface HeaderProps {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    className?:string;
}

const Header: React.FC<HeaderProps> = ({children,className}) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const handleLogout = ()=>{
        //;
    }
  return (
     <div  className={twMerge(`h-fit bg-gradient-to-b from-emerald-800 p-6`,className)}>Home</div>
  )
}

export default Header;

tailwind.config.ts
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}


